# Upload To Google Drive File Not Found Exception

Tags: java, android, file

I want to programmatically access a specific Excel spreadsheet which will be included in my project folder and upload it to Google Drive. I am including the spreadsheet within my src folder and using the following code:

```
private void saveFileToDrive() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    URL fileURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx");
                    String filePath2 = fileURL.getPath();

                    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filePath2);
                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.ms-excel", fileContent);

                    File body = new File();
                    body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                    body.setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel");


                    File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).setConvert(true).execute();

                    if (file != null) {
                        showToast("File uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                    }
                    else
                             ;
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {

                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

However, I keep getting the following FileNotFoundException:

```
11-29 14:43:45.189: W/System.err(21133): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/data/app/com.example.drivequickstart-2.apk!/Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?

EDIT:
I have tried to modify my code as follows in line with suggestions below:

```
private void saveFileToDrive() {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                      String mime = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                     InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx");
                     InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(mime, in);;

                        File body = new File();
                        body.setTitle("Untitled spreadsheet");
                        body.setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel");


                        File file = service.files().insert(body, content).setConvert(true).execute();

                        if (file != null) {
                            showToast("File uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                        }
                        else
                                 ;
                    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {

                        startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833):     at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.getMediaContentLength(MediaHttpUploader.java:328)
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:347)
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:266)
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:408)
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:328)
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:449)
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833):     at com.example.drivequickstart.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:303)
11-29 20:31:08.118: E/AndroidRuntime(9833):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

and points to the line:  `File file = service.files().insert(body, content).setConvert(true).execute();` Upon closer inspection, I discovered that the length of the InputStreamContent is -1, so the problem probably originates there.

Comment: So, if you (correctly) think that the problem is the InputStreamContent's length, why don't you try to set it?

Comment: Since the resource is an asset, you can compute the length on your development machine - otherwise you can read from the input stream one byte at a time (or really with a buffer) until the EOS, and then set the content length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the Java idiom `ClassLoader.getResource()` to load resources from the `CLASSPATH`. However, that's not how we do it on Android.

You'll place your file in the `assets/` directory or in `res/raw/`, and then retrieve it with the [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) or an identifier like `R.raw.untitled_spreadsheet.xlsx`.

See [the official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html):

> While uncommon, you might need access your original files and
>   directories. If you do, then saving your files in res/ won't work for
>   you, because the only way to read a resource from res/ is with the
>   resource ID. Instead, you can save your resources in the assets/
>   directory.
>
> Files saved in the assets/ directory are not given a resource ID, so
>   you can't reference them through the R class or from XML resources.
>   Instead, you can query files in the assets/ directory like a normal
>   file system and read raw data using AssetManager.
>
> However, if all you require is the ability to read raw data (such as a
>   video or audio file), then save the file in the res/raw/ directory and
>   read a stream of bytes using openRawResource().

Speaking in code, if you put the file in `assets/sheet.xlsx`:

```
String mime = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
InputStream in = ctx.getAssets().open("sheet.xlsx");
InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(mime, in);
```

where `ctx` is a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). Since `Activity` is a `Context` you can skip the `ctx` and directly call `getAssets()` if you happen to write this code inside an `Activity`.

Notice I didn't use a `FileContent`: instead I choosed `InputStreamContent` because you don't really have a `java.io.File` object, but [an input stream](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/2fe3287eff6e00294deaa1deffd32a7fa8884c37/apis/drive/v1/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.html).

Basically, you are asking the Drive client: *"Read bytes from this local stream, upload them and make them accessible under the name $NAME"*. The name `$NAME` is supplied to the service via a `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File` object's `title` field, which can be whatever you like - I think it can include directory separators, too.

This is a link to the [Javadoc for Google Drive V2](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/index.html)

Comment: But how do I get the file path from the InputStreamContent?

Comment: What file path? The `InputStreamContent` is just that, a wrapper around an input stream which represents the local resource in the apk

Comment: The Drive's `File` object represents metadata of the file stored in the cloud. To upload a file (either a new one or an update) you don't need any metadata: just an array of bytes and a MIME type - and that's what `InputStreamContent` is for. Then you need a `File` object to tell how this byte stream will be called in the cloud. Note that this is not a `java.io.File`, but a Drive [File](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html). You will call `setTitle()` with whichever name you like

Comment: Your last suggestion worked like a charm. I do find it unusual though that I have to manually set this length property.

Comment: @JohnRoberts indeed it is. HTTP doesn't strictly need it, there must be a way to skip the measure, however it's not easy to tell how - it seems that when `Transfer-Encoding` is set to `chunked`, you can skip the `Content-Length` header. This should be the default behavior, but maybe I didn't read the doc very well...

Answer (score 0):

To tackle your question of "What is causing this?", refer to the discussion [here](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-13711.html) (around comment #13).

> It's a simple reason that you are not giving it a valid file path. You
>   are getting a resource from the classloader, and that resource is
>   coming from a jar (which is actually never unpacked into the
>   filesystem).
>
> So when you ask the URL of the resource for the path with
>   url.getPath() you get back a 
>   (**in your case**) file:/data/app/com.example.drivequickstart-2.apk!/Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx
>
> this is not a legal 'file:' url string!

He also suggests a very apt way to tackle this:

> What you should do is just feed to the constructors the String
>   returned by URL.toString(). What you should get back then is some sort
>   of registered url type that still points into the jar file, but the
>   url resolver in your VM knows how to handle.

Comment: Passing in URL.toString() instead of the file path produced the same error.