# File not fond exception while uploading to drive

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, filenotfoundexception, drive

I have checked the past questions and they do not help in this situation.
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634434/upload-to-google-drive-file-not-found-exception)

[FileNotFoundException when CREATING a google drive file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58623949/filenotfoundexception-when-creating-a-google-drive-file)

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634434/upload-to-google-drive-file-not-found-exception)

In my case, I am trying to upload a file that I received in a curl request to drive.

```
public static void uploadFile(Drive driveService, java.io.File fileToUpload, String name){
        File fileMetadata = new   File();
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(name)){
            name = "Test";
        }
        fileMetadata.setName(name);
        fileMetadata.setMimeType(SHEETS_MIME_TYPE);

        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(XLSX_FILE_APPLICATION_TYPE, fileToUpload);
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                    .setFields(ID_FIELD)
                    .execute();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("File ID: {} " , file.getId());
    }
```

As you can see, fileToUpload field passes the file that was received as part of the curl request. However, whenever I try to upload it, I get this error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: files (No such file or directory)`

Thanks

EDIT -

The code for generating the file object fileToUpload:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public String uploadFileToDrive(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws Exception {
        if(Objects.isNull(multipartFile)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No file present");
        }
        File file = new File(multipartFile.getName());
        multipartFile.transferTo(file);
        GoogleDriveClientService.uploadFile(driveService, file, "spring1");
```

Comment: By this sentence, "fileToUpload field passes the file that was received as part of the curl request." Would you be able to share the contents of fileToUpload? Also, have you tried using the exact directory of the file you are trying to download ?

Comment: When I use a debugger I can't actually see the contents. The value is "files". How do I look up the exact directory where it is being saved? Is it just passing the name and nothing else? Updated the post with more code as well